# Infinite loop in Observe liveData

Tags: java, android, infinite-loop

I'm using the MVVM architecture on my code project but I encounter infinite loop

```
final boolean[] isUpdating = {false};
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (!isUpdating[0]) {
                Users user = new Users(5, "juan", "14", "14");
                userViewModel.getUser(user.getUsername()).observe(this, users -> {
                    try {
                        isUpdating[0] = true;
                        if (!(users.equals(userViewModel.getUser(user.getUsername()).getValue()))) {
                            int result = userViewModel.update(user);


                        if (result > 0) {
                            logger.LogError(tag, "Update", "success");
                        } else {
                            logger.LogError(tag, "Update", "failed");
                        }
                        }

                    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        isUpdating[0] = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is the message that I got. I tried using Boolean flag and other validation to stop the loop but didn't do anything

```
2023-03-28 16:39:47.492 11377-11377/com.example.aoapp E/mLOG -> APP VIEW -> UserViewModel: Update -> {"id":5,"password":"14","password2":"14","username":"kylo"}
2023-03-28 16:39:47.496 11377-11377/com.example.aoapp E/mLOG -> APP VIEW -> com.example.aoapp.MainActivity: Update -> success
2023-03-28 16:39:47.499 11377-11377/com.example.aoapp E/mLOG -> APP VIEW -> UserViewModel: Update -> {"id":5,"password":"14","password2":"14","username":"kylo"}
2023-03-28 16:39:47.501 11377-11377/com.example.aoapp E/mLOG -> APP VIEW -> com.example.aoapp.MainActivity: Update -> success
2023-03-28 16:39:47.503 11377-11377/com.example.aoapp E/mLOG -> APP VIEW -> UserViewModel: Update -> {"id":5,"password":"14","password2":"14","username":"kylo"}
2023-03-28 16:39:47.507 11377-11377/com.example.aoapp E/mLOG -> APP VIEW -> com.example.aoapp.MainActivity: Update -> success
```

Comment: so you setup observer and then call something which would trigger the observer ... What is you expected ? ... you should prolly check if it is updating inside observer ... (of course it is just blind guess with assumption that `userViewModel.update` would trigger the observer - since you didn;t provide relevant code)

Answer (score 0):

Per the code snippet you shared.
Inside the callback on update received from the livedata observing. you call:
`int result = userViewModel.update(user);`
what does `userViewModel.update(user)` do?
does it update the LiveData object with new value?
If so, it will trigger another call of the whole code snippet you sent. which in turn will create an infinite loop.

But it is very hard to give a straight answer due to a lot of missing information.

Edit -
*It seems to me that the mistake is starting with the `if (!(users.equals(userViewModel.getUser(user.getUsername()).getValue())))` condition that you have, that it doesn't actually check if you need to update the value*